# php foreach array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm currently using XenForo to read values from an array inside an array, however when using this code I seem to get issues with the last foreach. `ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Array

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "server",
    "id": "121",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "1",
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 4000,
    },
  },
}
```

This is my foreach (which is getting the 'attributes' section of the above array).

```
foreach($json_array as $key => $arrays){
    foreach($arrays as $array){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if there's a better way to just get the following values?

```
$value['name']
$value['ip']
$value['port']
```

Comment: `foreach($json_array['data']['attributes'] as $key => $value)`. Your issue is your code is using non-array values like `"server"` in `foreach`

Comment: which foreach should be changed? first/second/third? or redo the entire foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$data['name'] = $json_array['data']['attributes']['name'];
$data['ip'] = $json_array['data']['attributes']['ip'];
$data['port'] = $json_array['data']['attributes']['port'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop:

```
foreach($json_array['data']['attributes'] as $key => $value){
  print_r($value);
}
```

Comment: I'd say `$key` is also important within the loop

Answer (score -3):

Quite simple. To get the attributes of the given array, you can try the code above.
No need to loop the array, just use $array[key] method to get the target value.

```
$data = $json_array['data']['attributes']
```